# python if statement always returns False

Tags: python, if-statement, jinja2

I am new to the world of Python. I have this `'if statement'` in my jinja2 template:

```
{{context.disabled==True and "Yes" or "No"}}
```

I am not sure what this syntax is called, but it works like an `if`.

php equivalent would be: `echo $disabled ?  "Yes" :  "No"`

This is always returning `No` or `False` even though `context.disabled` is `True`,

Why is it behaving like this? I cant see why it is doing this, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: try removing `==True` part

Comment: @alko I have tried this... and it behaves the same.thank you for your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about boolean expressions in jinja templates, but you can use [conditions](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/switching/#conditions):

```
{% if context.disabled %} "Yes" {% else %} "No" {% endif %}
```

Comment: @Renier what is output of `{{context.disabled}}`?

Comment: I feel like such an idiot.... I had the variable spelt wrong :(... it works now, but thanks for all your help :).. it is `disability` not `disabled`...@alko Ill accept your answer as it was the most helpful.

Answer (score 6):

What you want is something like this:

```
value = "Yes" if context.disabled else "No"
```

Comment: please explain your code? as I do not know/understand how the `value="Yes"` does? sorry if its a dumb question

Comment: @Renier It's just assignment to a reference.

Comment: @DerekLitz how is it related to templates?

Comment: @alko I assume because the templating language uses Python semantics.

Comment: @DerekLitz In templates, a subset usually (it's a long time since I used jinja, so not sure if this is constructive answer to the question). For example, do you know, is {{"Yes" if context.disabled else "No"}} valid in templates?

Comment: @alko I agree, don't know Jinja2 myself.  The best answer would certainly be a working Jinja2 solution.

Answer (score 0):

It should be
{{ 'Yes' if context.disabled else 'No' }}